# How to copy/paste an OverHat symbol into Microsoft Word 2010 properly?

Tags: output-formatting, office

I have problem with output traditional form of sign above the constant. When I copy/paste in word it is far away up. Is there solution for this?

```
 BB /: MakeBoxes[BB[n_], TraditionalForm] := 
 RowBox[{SubscriptBox["\!\(\*
 StyleBox[OverscriptBox[
 StyleBox[\"A\",\nFontFamily->\"Times New Roman\",\n\
 FontWeight->\"Plain\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"], \"^\"],\nFontFamily\
 ->\"Times New Roman\",\nFontWeight->\"Plain\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"\
  ]\)", RowBox[{Sequence @@ 
   Riffle[Table["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(c\), \(1\)]\)", {1}], 2]}]]}]

BB[1] // TraditionalForm
BB[2] // TraditionalForm
```

Comment: It seems to me Word 2013 uses `FromCharacterCode[770]` instead of `FromCharacterCode[94]` (i.e. the ordinary ^) for the overhat.

Comment: how to fix it in word 2010? What is charactercode?

Comment: I don't have 2010 aside. But I think they can use the same **MathML** syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a Word 2010 aside. But I think the MathML syntax would be the some. The following method works for my Word 2013.

Create the desired formula in Word with the built-in formula editor:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then copy and paste it into Mathematica:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Check the cell expression:

```
Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox[
  TagBox[
   SubscriptBox[
    OverscriptBox["A", "^",
     DiacriticalPositioning->True], 
    SubscriptBox["c", "2"]],
   "MathMLPresentationTag",
   AutoDelete->True], TraditionalForm]], "Input"]
```

So we have our magic spell, an `OverscriptBox` with the option of `DiacriticalPositioning -> True`!

Thus a definition like the following should work fine with MS Word:

```
BB /: MakeBoxes[BB[n_], TraditionalForm] := 
 SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox["A", "^", DiacriticalPositioning -> True],
   SubscriptBox["c", n]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or **Copy As** -> **MathML**, then paste in Word.

Comment: @Pipe You're welcome :) Thanks for accepting.

Comment: Perfect, congrats. I can male similar code for brackets also? Instead of traditional form  u(v(r(b))) to get this u{v[r(b)]}, I am not sure how to recognize order of brackets? Thank you very much in any case. Regards, Pipe :)

Comment: @Pipe Yes I think the principle behind is the same. MathML is a very useful intermediary for transferring formulas.